# Cells on UITableView disappearing after scrolling or touching the table

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am implementing a [SwipeMenuViewController](https://github.com/yysskk/SwipeMenuViewController) and when the user starts scrolling or tapping the cell disappears. I am not sure if it is due to the tableView being implemented not properly or the SwipeMenuViewController not being implemented properly.

Before swiping/touching the table, as you can see the table was loaded with the data

[image]

However. Once we start swiping or even touching the table, the previous cell disappears:

[image]

I have implemented the table view into a ViewController as follows

```
var currentUser: User!
var requests = [User]() 
var myTableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    myTableView = UITableView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableSize.width, height: tableSize.height))
    myTableView.register(UINib(nibName: "FriendRequestTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "friendRequest")
    myTableView.dataSource = self
    myTableView.delegate = self
    //myTableView.separatorStyle = .none
    myTableView.rowHeight = 103
    myTableView.backgroundColor = Colours.flatColour.main.offWhite
    self.view.addSubview(myTableView)

}
```

The protocol methods:

```
// MARK: - Table view data source

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if (self.requests.count == 0) {
        self.myTableView.setEmptyMessage("You are up to date!\nYou dont have any notifications ")
    } else {
        self.myTableView.restore()
    }

    return requests.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("FriendRequestTableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! FriendRequestTableViewCell

    cell.currentUser = currentUser
    cell.requestFriendDelegate = self
    cell.user = requests[indexPath.row]

    return cell

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 103
}
```

Does anyone have an idea as to where I have gone wrong, I am not sure if I am missing any code. The example of `SwipeMenuViewController` does not show this way of implementation. I have followed the Read me on implementing `SwipeMenuView`. I have two ViewControllers, one which holds the `SwipeMenuView` and one which holds the table for each tab which is the controller I think the issue is coming from. Thank you for any help

The notificationsViewController class:

```
class NotificationsViewController: UIViewController, SwipeMenuViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var swipeMenuView: SwipeMenuView! {
    didSet {
        swipeMenuView.delegate = self
        swipeMenuView.dataSource = self
        var options: SwipeMenuViewOptions = .init()
        options.tabView.style = .flexible
        options.tabView.margin = 20.0
        options.tabView.additionView.backgroundColor = Colours.flatColour.yellow.lighter //UIColor.black//UIColor.customUnderlineColor
        options.tabView.itemView.textColor = Colours.flatColour.main.gray
        options.tabView.itemView.selectedTextColor = Colours.flatColour.yellow.lighter //UIColor.black//UIColor.customSelectedTextColor
        options.tabView.itemView.font = UIFont(name: "Biotif-Medium", size: 14)!

        swipeMenuView.reloadData(options: options)
    }
}

var tabTitles: [String] = ["All", "Friend Requests", "Items"]
var requests = [User]()
```

}

I `reloadData` again when populating the requests array and the array isnt empty.
The data source methods:

```
extension NotificationsViewController: SwipeMenuViewDataSource {

//MARK - SwipeMenuViewDataSource
func numberOfPages(in swipeMenuView: SwipeMenuView) -> Int {
    return tabTitles.count
}

func swipeMenuView(_ swipeMenuView: SwipeMenuView, titleForPageAt index: Int) -> String {
    return tabTitles[index]
}

func swipeMenuView(_ swipeMenuView: SwipeMenuView, viewControllerForPageAt index: Int) -> UIViewController {
    let vc = NotificationsContentTable()
    vc.currentUser = currentUser
    vc.tableSize = swipeMenuView.bounds.size
    if index == 0 {
        vc.requests = requests
    }else if index == 1 {
        vc.requests = []
    }else if index == 2 {
        vc.requests = []
    }
    print("the requests are in = \(vc.requests)")
    return vc
}
```

}

Comment: where you are confirming to swipemenuviewcontroller ?

Comment: I don't, I use swipeMenuView instead. I use the SwipeMenuViewDelegate and SwipeMenuViewDataSource on this swipeMenuView which is in NotificationsViewController() class, this class holds the swipeMenuView. I will update the question to show the NotificationsViewController class

Comment: The problem is with `requests`, somewhere it is setting as empty. so `requests[indexPath.row]` this returns empty cell.

Comment: @karthik I am not sure that this is the issue, before implementing this swipeMenuView I had a regular table view and the requests showed there perfectly. If it is getting set to empty I cannot seem to find it. I have searched "requests" in both files and cannot see anywhere that the data is removed. Thank you.

Comment: @AndrewHarris , you get the solve issue?? if yes give me demo code of your project , i get same issue after the applied below code and structure, give me link of your demo code..,Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I've figured out where I was going wrong. Before returning the viewController in `viewControllerForPageAt`, you must add that viewController as a child with `addChild(viewController)`.